# Postgres regex to restrict forbidden characters and limit number of consequtive caps

Tags: regex, postgresql

I want to add few identical constraints to 2 tables (on multiple columns).

To this end I want to create functions to be used in check constraint.

The validation should fail if the value contains any of the following (the string will always contain at least some letters):

- `..` (two consequent dots)
- `>`
- `<`
- more, than 3 consecutive *capital* letters
- all letters are capital (must contain at least 1 lowercased letter)

So far I have the following:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION no_forbidden_characters(text) RETURNS boolean
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT
AS $_$
  SELECT $1 !~ '[a-z]+|..|>|<';
$_$;
```

Not sure how to get the max 3 capital letters in a row (though allowing for multiple separate by a space 3 capital letter combinations)

Comment: Try `'[.]{2}|[<>]|[[:upper:]]{4}|^[[:upper:]]+$'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I forgot to mention it must allow for 3 dots `...`, sorry! (I will then have a function transforming `...` into an ellipsis character

Comment: Then try `(^|[^.])[.]{2}([^.]|$)|[<>]|[[:upper:]]{4}|^[[:upper:]]+$`

Comment: now it doesn't validate for non-all-capital-letters (it should contain at least one lowercased letter), but you already provided great help, thanks a lot!

Comment: If the condition is "not all capital and at least one lowercase letter", then just write so. `^[[:upper:]]+$` matches a string composed of only uppercase letters.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew actually I was rushing for the conclusion, you're right - no need for that addition I mentioned!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use

```sql
(^|[^.])[.]{2}([^.]|$)|[<>]|[[:upper:]]{4}|^[[:upper:]]+$
```

It matches (and thus, since you are using the negated regex matching operator, rejects) the following patterns:

- `(^|[^.])[.]{2}([^.]|$)` - two dots that is preceded with start of string or a non-dot char and followed with a non-dot char or end of string (so, only `..` string, no `...`)
- `[<>]` - a `<` or `>`
- `[[:upper:]]{4}` - four consecutive uppercase letters
- `^[[:upper:]]+$` - a string fully composed of uppercase letters.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KnwSYI/1).

Comment: Thank you again for your help! I've posted another question with allegedly a bit more complex requirements: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64987441/postgres-regex-with-multiple-rules. If you could take a look I'd appreciate.